# Email password asked when trying to convert pdf to word, is this a phishing site?

Tags: passwords, phishing

This morning, while trying to convert a .pdf file to Word at [Nitro](https://www.pdftoword.com/en/), I was asked for my email address first to send the converted file. This is very natural. But as soon as I hit the **`Convert Now`** button, another box appeared asking for a password.

[image]

I found this to be extremely suspicious and aborted the job then and there.

Is this a phishing site or am I missing something here?

I did not find any feature for membership registration at the site so I don't think that this is a membership password.

Comment: I've seen some other websites that do this; if the account doesn't exist with the email address the password box is used to type in a password for the account and then complete the registration. If the account already exists, it'll ask for the account's password, and will throw an error if the incorrect password is entered. It's quite seamless, but it isn't something I like tbh.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 Perhaps what you are saying is true. But shouldn't there be a notification explaining this? I was somewhat perplexed seeing like that in a seemingly honorable site. But you can not be too careful these days, can you?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 Please try the site again. Looks like things got more interesting. When I press the convert button, everything dims without further activity.

Comment: I agree with Sonickyle27.  It's either a phishing-esque site (remember the [unroll.me backlash](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/04/25/unroll-me-backlash-shows-us-exactly-whats-wrong-with-privacy-policies/)?) or, more likely, it's an account registration form with bad UI.  Try a password that you're comfortable with for this site and that is definitely not your email password and see what happens.  That said, I can't make any guarantees on the safety of this site, the privacy of your PDF data, or their usage of your password.

Comment: It's also possible that they're encrypting the content to you via email and that's the document or archive password, but I think that's the least likely of the possibilities presented so far.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, this is most likely a registration form for a user account. Thus it is not asking your email account password but asking you to input a new password for this specific site, registering as a user.

This is most often done in an effort to make a service easy to use and reduce the so called "hassle hurdle" that usually entails lengthy registrations forms prior to service usage.

In this simple form, you can probably simultaneously register and use the service, but there seems to be UI missing to convey that information.

Nonetheless, because you hopefully do not practice password reuse, you should be fine just using a new password for this site and use it.

While it is not exactly clear to me as to why a registration is needed, this is probably dictated by their business model and/or legal reasons.

Comment: I would say that the reason why a registration is needed is simple: because more registrations = more customers = more people to upsell on additional services.  I'm sure it is simply a business need, rather than a technical need.  Having someone's email address on hand is nice (which they would already have), but having them registered on your system makes it even easier to get them to put a credit card number on your site and get them to start buying.  I've worked with many business owners who have this mindset.